# Microsoft Sync Framework and Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, microsoft-sync-framework

I am needing to move an application to a different server.  This application uses Microsoft Sync Framework.  I have looked over the FAQ and forums on the Microsoft site, and have not found a decent answer to my question.

Does Microsoft Sync Framework run on Windows Server 2012?  Whatever the answer could you provide a website/documentation to help back up your answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it should run on Windows Server 2012. I can't give you any link as it's based on my own experience. Likewise, don't expect to hear back from the product group as they have been inactive for a couple of years already.